# Using Ansible Vault-ID

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

Currently having trouble using the password of a vault credential I set up via Ansible Tower. Here is a screenshot of the credential. How can I access the variable when I execute a Job Template? The credential is added on the Job Template UI already in Ansible Tower.

[image]

I have currently looked around on Stack Overflow to no avail. Is there a trivial way to do this?